# TLE2141 op-amp alternative (in DC load circuit)

Tags: operational-amplifier, dc, electronic-load, alternatives

I recently found a schematic for a DIY electronic load, which I think is based on Dave Jones's EEVBlog old DC load design (attaching the source link: [Dynamic DC Power Load (updated)](http://www.paulvdiyblogs.net/2015/08/dynamic-dc-power-load.html), but I am attaching the schematic too):

[image: DC Load schematic]

The problem is that it is using the TLE2141 op-amp, which seems to be difficult to me to find. I have already searched for an alternative, but I can't find anything useful.

So can you tell me some alternative/equivalent op-amp I can use?

Comment: MC34071, as many of the specs are the same, but it *might* be hard to find as a DIP - you don't specify, whether you require SMD or DIP.

Comment: You also do not specify whether control pin 5 is an issue. It is not an issue here so you can use most any op-amp (except a 741), at long as it is specified to work with single ended supplies, which rules out most Jfet op-amps. Note that you are asking us to shop for you, which is off-topic on this site.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and sorry if my question is off-topic. I will use a DIP package generic jfet op-amp as you said and how it goes.

Comment: PS: If anyone else has any suggestion please let me know, thanks again.